# Eclipse remote debugging - source not found

Tags: java, eclipse, remote-debugging

i am trying to debug code deployed on our staging server via eclipse. i configured debug configuration to point to staging host and port. the code in my local is slightly different than the one deployed at staging(couple of jsp changes here n there) everytime i try to debug the code, it says source not found.can that be due too slight code difference or the fact that the project folder is named differently on my local. i am very new to this and scratching my head as to why this is happening.any help would be appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Seems, you are deploying to a _web server_ or so. Can you add some details, about the exact set up?

Comment: Can you give the exact error? Is it an eclipse output? Folder names don't matter but make sure your source lookup path is correct (in the debug configuration you run).

Comment: Verhagen - ear is deployed to jboss in the remote server.there are two  jboss application servers running in clusters. i am trying to debug code by pointing to one of them.

Comment: Gene Martin - Can you please help me understand what do you mean by source lookup path is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added all modules of the project like in the screnshot [In the source tab, modules of the project should be added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBX5k.png)

Answer (score 0):

try to change the source lookup path to point to \src\main (or only \src) inside your project

also there is a checkbox which says that search for duplicate source files on the path. Try by checking that true too also and see if it works